# Criar efeito de botão apertado

Tags: javascript, react, onclick, eventos

Tenho o seguinte componente no React:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      count: parseInt(this.props.value)
    };

    this.inc = this.inc.bind(this);
    this.dec = this.dec.bind(this);
  }

  inc() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  }

  dec() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count - 1 });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          O valor inicial é: <code>{this.props.value}</code>.
        </p>
        <div>
          O valor <strong>atual</strong> é: <code>{this.state.count}</code>.
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.inc}>Incrementar</button>
          <button onClick={this.dec}>Decrementar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = Counter;
```

Ele basicamente tem um número, que, ao pressionar um botão, é incrementado em um. Desse modo, a cada clique, o valor aumenta um.

Como faço para que, ao manter esse botão pressionado (mantendo o botão esquerdo do mouse pressionado), o valor continue a ser aumentado (até que eu pare de pressionar o botão esquerdo)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defina dentro do método construtor uma variável, exemplo:

```
this.interval = null;
```

Ela ira guardar o temporizador [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), agora crie um método para limpar o temporizador:

```
clear() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.interval = null;
}
```

No método construtor faça o bind do novo método:

```
this.clear = this.clear.bind(this);
```

Deve fazer a seguintes modificações nos métodos `inc` e `dec`:

```
inc() {
    if (this.interval === null) {
        this.interval = setInterval(this.inc, 100);
    }
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
}

dec() {
    if (this.interval === null) {
        this.interval = setInterval(this.dec, 100);
    }
    if (this.state.count > 0) {
        this.setState({ count: this.state.count - 1 });
    }
}
```

Altere os eventos `onClick` para `onMouseDown` e adicione o evento `onMouseUp` o qual ira executar o método `clear`, ficando assim o código:

```
<button onMouseUp={this.clear} onMouseDown={this.inc}>Incrementar</button>
<button onMouseUp={this.clear} onMouseDown={this.dec}>Decrementar</button>
```

#### Exemplo funcionando

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      count: parseInt(this.props.value)
    };
    this.interval = null;
    this.clear = this.clear.bind(this);
    this.inc = this.inc.bind(this);
    this.dec = this.dec.bind(this);
  }

  inc() {
    if (this.interval === null) {
      this.interval = setInterval(this.inc, 100);
    }
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  }

  dec() {
    if (this.interval === null) {
      this.interval = setInterval(this.dec, 100);
    }
    if (this.state.count > 0) {
      this.setState({ count: this.state.count - 1 });
    }
  }

  clear() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.interval = null;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          O valor inicial é: <code>{this.props.value}</code>.
        </p>
        <div>
          O valor <strong>atual</strong> é: <code>{this.state.count}</code>.
        </div>
        <div>
          <button className="inc" onMouseUp={this.clear} onMouseDown={this.inc}>Incrementar</button>
          <button className="dec" onMouseUp={this.clear} onMouseDown={this.dec}>Decrementar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Counter value="0" />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
button {
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.inc {
  background: #388E3C;
  margin-right: 14px;
}
.dec {
  background: #E57373;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

> Se preferir você pode ver funcionando em [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/jvonkwn9l5)

#### Referência

- [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)
- [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Bem legal. É isso aí.